# "could not initialize a collection" + @Lob + MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

When using **Blob**-fields in n-to-m-relations **Hibernate** and **MSSQL** are failing for some reason.

```
SQL Error: 421, SQLState: S0001
The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
...
could not initialize a collection: [Dataset.documents#someID]
```

My classes look as follows:

```
@Entity
class Dataset {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();
}

@Entity
class Document {
    @Id
    public long id;

    @Lob
    public byte[] data;
}
```

Any ideas on this? I already tried using a `Set` or `Document[]` to avoid the errors. It seems that Hibernate always tries a distinct SELECT on my tables. How can I workaround this?

[1] [MSSQL error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645611.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been interesting to post the executed queries and the tables. But one difference I can think of between the two mappings (unidirectional one-to-many vs a bidirectional) is the way they're represented at the database level.

By default, a **unidirectional** one-to-many will use a join table:

```
DATASET       DATASET_DOCUMENT       DOCUMENT
-------       ----------------       --------
ID            DATASET_ID             ID
              DOCUMENT_ID
```

While a **bidirectional** will use the following representation:

```
DATASET       DOCUMENT  
-------       ----------
ID            ID        
              DATASET_ID
```

In JPA 2.0, it is now possible to use a unidirectional association without a join table (in a **standard** way) by specifying a `@JoinColumn` on the `@OneToMany` side:

```
@Entity
class Dataset {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="DATASET_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    public List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();
}
```

I would give the above a try.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 11.1.21 "JoinColumn Annotation"
- JPA Wikibook

  - [Undirectional OneToMany, No Inverse ManyToOne, No Join Table (JPA 2.0)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0.29)

Comment: You are right, this is exactly how it is done. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a reversed reference to my `Document` class. I am sure there is a more direct way, because I do not need this reference at all, so it basically only helps to workaround the problem.

```
@Entity
class Dataset {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dataset")
    public List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();
}

@Entity
    class Document {
    @Id
    public long id;

    @Lob
    public byte[] data;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    public Dataset dataset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this in another way.
I already had the `mappedBy = "enrollment"` on my OneToMay and on my ManyToOne I had a `@JoinColumn(name="enrollment", nullable=true)`. So this was not a relation issue.

Instead I found a post on the hibernate forum suggesting overriding the `supportsUnionAll()` from the Dialect class. It defaults returns false, but SQL Server has since v6.5 supported `UNION ALL`. Remember the extend SQLServerDialect if you have not done so already.
So this could be another possible solution for the "The * data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable" error.